# Fluid height columns in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

When people build the "holy grail" website design using flexbox with a fixed-width column, a fluid-width column, and then another fixed-width column, they seem to want equal heights for all their columns. What if I want fluid height for all three, so that they are only as tall as the content within them? How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `align-items: flex-start` on the parent. The default is `align-items: stretch`.

Here's a good [flexbox reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: THAT was my problem! I didn't know I had to put that in the PARENT box! Thanks!

Comment: There's `align-self` on the item itself, but if you want uniform behavior on all flex elements, setting this on the parent is better.